# How to maintain release versions of the API

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io

Is there a way to maintain history of API releases in Apiary Blueprint? I would like to show a dropdown with release versions on my API documentation page so that user could view documentation for a specific version of the API. May be by telling Apiary to list all branches or release tags from git.

For example: Angular documentation let us select "Doc Versions"